# Make a "remote: true" form submit AJAX synchronously

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Is there any way to perform an AJAX call for a form with `remote: true` synchronously?
Or is there a way to wait for AJAX request to complete with ease.

Comment: Synchronous ajax should be avoided. Once you learn to work with async code, it's not much harder than doing things synchronously.

Comment: 'Asynchronous' puts the 'A' in 'AJAX'.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! as **@adeneo** stated in the comments, *Synchronous AJAX* requests should be avoided because the other requests should wait until the current request is completed and I personally don't recommend it.

> Is there any way to perform an AJAX call for a form with remote: true
>   synchronously

AFAIK, there is no Rails way to achieve a synchronous request AJAX with `remote: true`

> Or is there a way to wait for AJAX request to complete with ease

Yes.AJAX by default do asynchronous requests.However you can achieve this with `async: false`

**Steps:**

- Have a normal form without `remote :true`
- Use Ajax with `async: false` on click of form submit

**Sample code:**

```
$("#submit-btn").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    url: "url",
    data: {the data}
  });
});
```